# Error: Main method not found in class Mult,please... or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Tags: java

I was currently writing a Java program for Multi-Threading and I got this weird error.

```
    Error: Main method not found in class Mult, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

I have wasted a lot of my time trying to figure out what the error was all about but I was unable to find any solution.I tried to google the problem,I found similar problems but all problems were somewhat different and I was unable to find any solutiion.
Please help. Below is the Code:

```
class A implements Runnable{
public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            System.out.println("Class A:"+i);
    }
}
class B implements Runnable{
public void run()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        System.out.println("Class B:"+i);

}
}
public class Mult{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Thread t1=new Thread(new A());
    Thread t2=new Thread(new B());
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

Comment: post the code in question

Comment: Please share the code in order to help you

Comment: I just wrote solution to a similar problem.Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744955/javafx-application-class-must-extend-javafx-application-application/48309505#48309505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suffered from a similar problem recently. It occurred because you might be having any class file in your directory which have same name as an inbuilt Java Class name. For e.g in my case,I was using String class when I passed it as a parameter to my main function as `public static void main(String args[])` and I was also having my own defined String class in the same directory. 
So I renamed my String which worked for me.
You can either rename/delete the your defined class name or you can change the directory.

Using Java's inbuilt class names to define your own class name is not a good practice.It can cause a lot of problems and confusion.